# Loading inconsistencies in using jquery html5lightbox

Tags: jquery, html

I've debugged different components of this website to understand that this website has combined html5lightbox and owl carousel but i cannot understand why the first time we call the lightbox, it fails to open full size.

https://lbs.com.my/property/simfoni-perdana/ here the link, and the html5lightbox call is situated at the Progress button.

Here is the code for it

```
<?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($progress): ?>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <a href="#progress-gallery" class="html5lightbox" data-width="900">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/hourglass.png">
                    <p>PROGRESS</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Where it calls

```
    <?php foreach($progress_images as $image): ?>
    <div class="product-banner-figure">
        <div class="item"> 
            <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" style=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <h3><?php echo $image['description'] ?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

It's not lazy load either. What could it be? Thanks!

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproduce-able example in your question. As soon as your code has been fixed, the question becomes useless.

Comment: Hi @BenM noted will edit the question